# Clicking on individual view of recyclerview and changing the icon ,text color and making some part of layout visible and invisible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement Onclicklistner on Recyclerview individual item.
I have the functionality to add when a single item is clicked
the functionalities are

1. I have to change the drawable image, the text view color and the color border of the view.
   2 I also have to make some views on the layout invisible like not showing the button in some particular views of the Recyclerview.
   I am having a hard time to solve this, please help

This is my RecyclerAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.awfis.vms.R;
import com.awfis.vms.model.DataModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.android.volley.VolleyLog.TAG;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    Context context;
    List<DataModel> mData;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<DataModel> mData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mData = mData;
    }



    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.typeofGuest.setText(mData.get(position).getText());
        holder.guestImage.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getDrawable());
        holder.mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.border_view_inpressed);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
        TextView typeofGuest;
        ImageView guestImage;
        boolean click = true;
        int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.guest, R.drawable.meetingroom_booking, R.drawable.centertour, R.drawable.housekeeping, R.drawable.delivery, R.drawable.vendor};
        int[] myImageList_one = new int[]{R.drawable.guest_two, R.drawable.meetingroom_booking_two, R.drawable.centertour_two, R.drawable.housekeeping_two, R.drawable.deliverytwo, R.drawable.vendor_two};

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mLinearLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycleritem_layout);
            typeofGuest = itemView.findViewById(R.id.guest_type);
            guestImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.guest_pic);
            typeofGuest.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (click) {
                mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
                typeofGuest.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
                guestImage.setImageResource(myImageList[getPosition()]);
                if (view.getId() == typeofGuest.getId()) {
                    if(getAdapterPosition()==1)
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    click = false;
                } else {
                    typeofGuest.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    guestImage.setImageResource(myImageList_one[getPosition()]);

                    click = true;
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

My model class

```
public class DataModel {
    public String text;
    public boolean isSelected;


    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public int drawable;

    public DataModel(){

    }

    public DataModel(String text, int drawable) {
        this.text = text;
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getDrawable() {
        return drawable;
    }

    public void setDrawable(int drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

}
```

This is my activity where I have to display the RecyclerView

```
public class AddVisitorActivity extends BaseActivity {
    List<DataModel>lsData;
    int spanCount = 3; // 3 columns
    int spacing = 50; // 50px
    boolean includeEdge = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_visitor);
        lsData= new ArrayList<>();
        lsData.add(new DataModel("Guest",R.drawable.guest_two));
        lsData.add(new DataModel("Metting Room Booking",R.drawable.meetingroom_booking_two));
        lsData.add(new DataModel("Center Tour",R.drawable.centertour_two));
        lsData.add(new DataModel("House Keeping",R.drawable.housekeeping_two));
        lsData.add(new DataModel("Delivery",R.drawable.deliverytwo));
        lsData.add(new DataModel("Vendor",R.drawable.vendor_two));
        RecyclerView mRecyclerview= findViewById(R.id.rvNumbers);
        RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,lsData);
        mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3));
        mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mRecyclerview.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(spanCount, spacing, includeEdge));
    }

}
```

My recyclerView item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_75sdp"
    android:id="@+id/recycleritem_layout"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/borde_view"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/guest_pic"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_27sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_27sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/guest" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guest_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/metting_room_booking"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

My add visitor activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_add_visitor"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_49sdp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/logo" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_350sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp">

            <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/addvisitor_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:text="@string/add_new_visitor"
                    android:textColor="@color/Textcolor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/addvisitor_text"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:text="@string/visitor_type"
                    android:textColor="@color/Textcolor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_7sdp" />


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvNumbers"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_60sdp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/select_host"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_270sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rvNumbers"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/borde_view"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3"
                    android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_9sdp"
                            android:text="@string/select_host"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_7sdp" />

                        <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
                            android:hint="@string/jhon_smith"
                            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_9sdp" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <Button
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/_44sdp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/_26sdp"
                            android:background="@color/CMbuttonColor"
                            android:text="@string/cm"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_270sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/select_host"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_7sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/splash_bg"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/MainLoginButtonColor"
                        android:text="@string/next"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[This is what I have to achieve by clicking changing the border color as well as when I select meeting room booking Cm option will become invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4NGK.png)

Comment: Can't you at least have the courtesy of displaying what you have already done?

Comment: without any code trials , the context of your question becomes too broad to perceive.

Comment: Yes sure I am sharing

Answer (score 0):

If the item data is not enough to decide which to display, you can consider using a wrapper ViewData class which holds the item data and the view state such as isButtonShown, imageUrl,... So based on the ViewData class, you can decide UI of ViewHolder

Comment: I am showing images from drawable folder not from url